# Expression Engine Discussion Forum Module URL

Tags: templates, url, forum, expressionengine

Has anyone ever successfully integrated the ExpressionEngine Discussion Module within regular templates?

I can include the code `{exp:forum}` into one of my templates and this successfully brings up the forum home page, but I get a 404 error on every link.

This happens because EE is writing out the forum links incorrectly.

Rather than this hyperlink being output:

> `/members/discussion-board/viewforum/1/`

I get something like this instead:

> `/members/viewforum/1/`

I understand that changing the forum URL to use `{segment_2}` instead of `{segment_1}` requires some additional setup.

I have followed the instructions for [Running the Forums Through Regular Templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates) with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

*I am using ExpressionEngine v2.2.2 with the Discussion Forum Module v3.1.4.*

Answer (score 1):

To enable the ExpressionEngine Discussion Forum to run as a different URL — on the second segment `{segment_2}` — you'll need to configure EE to **run the forum through regular templates**.

This [question has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272421/245264), but if you've already created the group and template, you just need to:

1. From the Control Panel, go to Add-Ons > Modules > Discussion Forum > Default Preferences
2. Configure your Forum Board Preferences to the following:

> **Forum Forum Board Short Name:** `discussion-board`
>   **Forum URL:** `http://example.com/index.php/members/discussion-board/`
>   **Forum Triggering Word:** `<empty>`

At this point, your forum will then be run inside the regular EE templating engine.

The forum is then accessed through whichever template you created above — the template name is used in place of the "trigger" word:

http://www.example.com/members/discussion-board/