# htaccess mod_rewrite Help for Expression Engine Forum Module

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, forum, expressionengine

I need to write a .htaccess rewrite command to make a certain URL behave like another.

A forum module I have installed over ExpressionEngine will not work unless the forum is situated on the first segment of the URL.

So I need to make: www.example.com/members/forum/

behave like: www.example.com/forum/

Comment: on Apache or IIS? If Apache I can help.

Comment: Why don't you just [change the forum URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8272421/245264) to `/members/forum/` and [run the forum thru regular templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates)? No `mod_rewrite` rules needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Forum URL to `/members/forum` and run the forum thru regular templates — no `mod_rewrite` rules needed.

Follow [these detailed instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272421/245264):

1. Create a new template group: `members`
2. Within that template group, create a new template: `forum`
3. In the `forum` template, put the following code: `{exp:forum}`
4. From the Control Panel, go to Add-Ons > Modules > Discussion Forum > Default Preferences
5. Configure your Forum Board Preferences to the following:

> **Forum Forum Board Short Name:** `forum`
>   **Forum URL:** `http://example.com/index.php/members/forum`
>   **Forum Triggering Word:** `<empty>`

At this point, your [forum will then be run inside the regular EE templating engine](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates).

The forum is then accessed through whichever template you created above — the template name used in place of the "trigger" word:

`http://www.example.com/members/forum/`

Your links will then be written out using the Forum URL specified in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(forum/.*)$ /members/$1
```

Comment: This RewriteRule will work, but unless the ExpressionEngine Discussion Forum settings are updated, the links will still be written out as `/members/forum/viewthread/1/`